# Status Bar Background during UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uimodaltransitionstyle

Attached are a few screenshots from my app in the midst of UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have changed the statusbarstyle to Black in info.plist and I have set the background color or MainWindow.xib to black.
Yet, during the UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal the background behind the statusbar is white. Any idea what I might be doing wrong here? and how I maybe able able to fix this (i.e. get rid the white)?

**UPDATE:** Here's what my statusbar starts looking like, if I set UIStatusBarStyle to UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent.

[image]

So, there is definitely something white behind the statusbar. :-(

Answer (score 1):

There are two option possible..

1. In **Info.plist** file add the below

   - `UIStatusBarStyle UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent`
     **or**
   - `UIStatusBarStyle UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque`
     **or**
   - `UIStatusBarStyle UIStatusBarStyleDefault`
2. Add the source in your application.

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                 setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:NO];

**or**

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
          setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:NO];
```

**or**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
      setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:NO];
```

**Update:**

for hide status bar

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both, but I'm using 
`UIStatusBarStyle UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` in Info.plist
and
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
      setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:NO];`
in source.

Just using opaque black instead of translucent, still during UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal the statusbar background shows a white as you can see in the screenshots above.

Comment: Tried. That just changes the color of the status bar when application is active. I can still see 20 pixels of white above the Navigation bar during UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal

Comment: Please read my question again, my friend. And, take a look at the screenshots attached. Do you see the white above the navigation bar while the view is flipping?
That's the white I want to get rid of.

Comment: Same issue with presentmodalviewcontroller.. during animation the status bar becomes translucent...